# ¿Cómo crear un hilo en C++ Ogre3D?

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy desarrollando un mini-juego en *C++* con *Ogre3D* y necesito lo siguiente.

1. Ejecutar `funcion1();`.
2. Esperar 6 segundos.
3. Ejecutar `funcion2();` y `funcion3();`.

Estuve viendo que se podría crear con esto:

```
std::thread th(funcion1);
th.detach();

#include <thread>
```

Parece ser que `funcion1()`, `funcion2()` y `funcion3()` deben ser `static`. Si pongo en `static` algunas de esas me generan problemas.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

**Error de Ogre:**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InternalErrorException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot create GL vertex buffer in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::GLHardwareVertexBuffer at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 47)
```

Parece que tengo que usar algo de esto, pero no entiendo: [Ogre](http://ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Threading)

Answer (score 1):

No tienen que ser funciones estáticas, el constructor de `std::thread` admite una función y un conjunto de parámetros que pasar a la misma. Mira este ejemplo de la documentación oficial

```
// example for thread::join
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::seconds

void pause_thread(int n) 
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(n));
  std::cout << "pause of " << n << " seconds ended\n";
}


int main() 
{
  std::cout << "Spawning 3 threads...\n";
  std::thread t1 (pause_thread,1);
  std::thread t2 (pause_thread,2);
  std::thread t3 (pause_thread,3);
  std::cout << "Done spawning threads. Now waiting for them to join:\n";
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  std::cout << "All threads joined!\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Aqui creas 3 nuevos hilos `t1, t2` y `t3`  que ejecutan `pause_thread` con diferentes parámetros.

Si vas a llamar a una función miembro (o método depende de quien te diera las clases de C++) necesitas usar la definición de INVOKE, te la resumo para no complicar la respuesta

```
std::thread t(&Clase::FuncionMiembro, puntero_a_instancia, parametro);
```

Lo que equivaldría a ejecutar `puntero_a_instancia->FuncionMiembro(parametro)` en el hilo `t`, pero te recomiendo que si vas a hacer algo parecido mejor uses lambdas.

Comment: acabo de editar mi pregunta, donde he puesto el error que me da al probar tu code.

Comment: me da error en Ogre, parece que recomiendan usar boost, te dejo un link (edite me pregunta), me podrías ayudar?

Comment: Pues de Ogre en si no tengo ni idea, pero en el enlace que das recomiendan que seas cuidadoso con los hilos. Por cierto, el error que da parece ser de algo de OpenGL y no creo que tenga que ver especialmente con hilos

Answer (score 0):

Ogre no tiene nada que ver con hilos. Tu pregunta se parece mucho a:

> ¿Cómo desayuno gachas llevando babuchas?

Una vez aclarado eso, veamos una solución a tu pregunta:

> 1. Ejecutar `funcion1();`.
> 2. Esperar 6 segundos.
> 3. Ejecutar `funcion2();` y `funcion3();`.

---

Para interrumpir la ejecución durante 6 segundos, debes usar [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) de la cabecera [`<thread>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread) que combinado con los literales de tiempo de [`<chrono>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) quedaría así:

```
void funcion1() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
void funcion2() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
void funcion3() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    funcion1();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(6s);
    funcion2();
    funcion3();
    return 0;
}
```

Si quieres que esto no suceda en el hilo principal, debes pasarlo a otro hilo:

```
void funcion1() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
void funcion2() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
void funcion3() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::thread hilo
    (
        []()
        {
            funcion1();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(6s);
            funcion2();
            funcion3();
        }
    );

    hilo.join();

    return 0;
}
```

En el ejemplo hago [`std::thread::join`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) para que la ejecución del programa espere a la ejecución del hilo, de no ser así el programa finaliza mientras el hilo está en marcha y provoca un error.

Comment: Me da error esta linea: using namespace std::chrono_literals;

Comment: ¿Tal vez no has incluido `<chrono>`?

Comment: si esta incluido.

Comment: como llamarías a funciones miembro con tu segundo bloque de código?

Comment: Llamar a funciones miembro de un objeto requiere una instancia de dicho objeto, deberías pasar el objeto a la función para ser usado.